# Django Sitemap and Absolute URL

Tags: django

I have an issue setting up a sitemap with my models. I am getting the following error. Reverse for '5555155555' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []. I think I have to pass a slug to the location but not 100% sure how I would accomplish this task.

```
#sitemap.py
from django.contrib.sitemaps import Sitemap
from django.contrib.flatpages.models import FlatPage
from django.urls import reverse
from phonenumbers.models import Phone


class PhoneSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "always"
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return Phone.objects.all()

    def location(self, obj):
        return reverse(obj)

    def lastmode(self, obj):
        return obj.created


class FlatpageSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "always"
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return FlatPage.objects.all()

#models.py
class Phone(models.Model):
    phone_number = models.CharField(blank=False, max_length=15) # validators should be a list
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    message = models.TextField()
    caller = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=CALLER_CHOICES, default="Unknown")
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.phone_number)
        super(Phone, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('phonenumbers:phone_details', args=[self.slug])

    def __str__(self):
        return self.phone_number

#urls.py
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.flatpages import views
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from .sitemap import PhoneSitemap, FlatpageSitemap


from info.views import home

sitemaps = {
    'posts': PhoneSitemap,
    'pages': FlatpageSitemap,
}

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', home, name="home"),
    url(r'^privacy-policy/$', views.flatpage, {'url': '/privacy-policy/'}, name='privacy-policy'),
    url(r'^terms-and-conditions/$', views.flatpage, {'url': '/terms-and-conditions/'}, name='terms-and-conditions'),
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', sitemap, {'sitemaps': sitemaps}, name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
    url(r'^whocalledme/', include('phonenumbers.urls', app_name="phonenumbers", namespace="phonenumbers")),
]
phonenumbers.urls
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^search/$', views.search_numbers, name="search_numbers"),
    url(r'^number/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.phone_detail, name="phone_detail"),
    url(r'^add_number/$', views.add_number, name='add_number'),
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/sitemap.xml

Django Version: 1.10.4
Python Version: 3.5.2
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.flatpages',
 'whitenoise.runserver_nostatic',
 'crispy_forms',
 'django.contrib.sitemaps',
 'phonenumbers']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



    Traceback:

    File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/info/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py" in inner
      39.             response = get_response(request)

    File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/info/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
      187.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

    File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/info/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in _get_response
      185.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

    File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/info/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/sitemaps/views.py" in inner
      16.         response = func(request, *args, **kwargs)

    File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/info/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/sitemaps/views.py" in sitemap
      68.                                       protocol=req_protocol))

    File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/info/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/sitemaps/__init__.py" in get_urls
      105.             urls = self._urls(page, protocol, domain)

    File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/info/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/sitemaps/__init__.py" in _urls
      114.             loc = "%s://%s%s" % (protocol, domain, self.__get('location', item))

    File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/info/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/contrib/sitemaps/__init__.py" in __get
      62.             return attr(obj)

    File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/info/info/info/sitemap.py" in location
      15.         return obj.get_absolute_url()

    File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/info/info/phonenumbers/models.py" in get_absolute_url
      25.         return reverse('phonenumbers:phone_details', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

    File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/info/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/base.py" in reverse
      91.     return force_text(iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs)))

    File "/Users/Tommy/Desktop/django/info/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
      392.             (lookup_view_s, args, kwargs, len(patterns), patterns)

    Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /sitemap.xml
    Exception Value: Reverse for 'phone_details' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{'slug': '2159642387'}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []
```

Answer (score 1):

The name is `phone_detail` in `urls.py` and `phone_details` (with an "s") in `get_absolute_url()`. They should both be the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I still get "get_absolute_url() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given" when I changed it.

Comment: Please put the full traceback in your question. That should help quite a bit.

Comment: Okay, the problem is you're passing `self` to `obj.get_absolute_url()`. Leave that off. Copy it exactly as it looks in my example.

Comment: That was my mistake. Alright so I have updated to exact code you provided but still running into a problem. I have replaced the traceback with a new one.

Comment: Got it, thanks! At this point we need to look at the urls at `phonenumbers/urls.py`. Please post the contents of that file as well. I believe the answer will be in there.

Comment: added just above the traceback.

Comment: The name is `phone_detail` in urls.py and `phone_details` (with an "s") in get_absolute_url. They should both be the same.

Comment: Sir you are a genius. It worked. I spent my whole day trying to track down the problem and can not believe that I did not catch that. Thank You!

Comment: It's always the little things. :) Happy to help.